# How to make a asynchronous thread in python that does not return control

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I have a django server built for a mobile app i.e. using JSON response.
The app has a simple social media feed.
The admins of the app have the ability to use push notifications (through firebase) on posting a new post to the feed.

At the movement the code is 'synchronous' and goes something like

```
def post(View):
    # validate post ect...
    # store it in database
    # ! Send push notifications !
    # return response
```

The issue is if firebase lags or is slow (which it sometimes seems to be) this can slow down the response. What I would like to do is make an asynchronous function that I can call to handle the push notification and forget about it and return the response to the user and the push notification can take as long as it needs.

[Meta]
Help in wording the title would be appreciated.

Comment: You Can Use Celery and RabbitMq or Redis as a message broker for this requirement. Check for using django with celery

Comment: as in batch them up? And send them every minute or so?

Comment: yes you can set up periodic task in celery using celerybeat. check this : https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html